# briss is not working on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, java

I just installed Xubuntu 16.04 (was running Xubuntu 14.04).

I noticed that the program briss, which crops pdf files, is not working (SIGSEGV, ya crash!). But it worked flawlessly on Xubuntu 14.04.

I have verified that both 14.04 and 16.04 use briss-0.9.jar, and that "java -version" gives the same outputs on both 14.04 and 16.04. I am not sure if this is a problem of briss or java.

How can I troubleshoot this issue? Note I know very little about java, but have extensive linux and programming experiences.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you install briss?

Comment: When you run Briss from a terminal window (with `java -jar ./briss-0.9.jar` or whatever), do you get any other errors or warnings in the terminal window when it crashes, or just the SIGSEGV?

Comment: Also, I remember having issues with Briss in the past, and happily transitioned to the very similar **PDF Scissors**: https://sites.google.com/site/pdfscissors/ ; this might be an option for you if you can't get briss working

Comment: @andrew.46: I downloaded from sourceforge.net, and applied gunzip (I also  used Thunar to extract). That gives me a directory containing briss-0.9.jar.

Comment: @Nick Weinberg: Here is the excerpt of long error message:
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5236703009, pid=12389, tid=12390
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
......
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.

Comment: @Nick Weinberg: Thanks for telling me about pdfscissors. I use chromium. When I clicked on the start button, it download the file pdfsissors.jnlp. What do I do with it? I did chmod +x on it, and try to run it, but that did not work.

Comment: I'm on a Mac right now, so I can't try it on Ubuntu, but it's a "Java Webstart" file. You might need the `icedtea-netx`or possibly the  `libnetx-java` Ubuntu package installed first, then you should be able to right-click the .jnlp file and "Open with Java Webstart". Sorry I can't be more specific or helpful, but it **is** opening and running properly on my Mac, so the .jnlp file must be ok!

Comment: @Nick Weinberg: Downloaded icedtea-netx, got pdfscissors working. Many thanks! I am still curious on why briss crashes.